# How to resolve this encoding error in RPostgresSQL?

Tags: r, postgresql, encoding

I'm saving from R a data frame that contents characters such "ñ" and "ó" in to a database.

My data contains the words "niños" and "talón" .

I save it to the db with the following code:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "data", data,overwrite=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
```

The I read it with this:

```
dbReadTable(con,"data")
```

And "niños" turned into " NI < c3>< 91>OS" and "talón" turned into "tal< c3>< b3>n" (I add spaces after "<" so it's visible).

I tried adding encoding when reading but it didn't work.

```
dbReadTable(con,"data",encoding = "latin-1")
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: did you try encoding in dbConnect(...,encoding='latin-1')?

Comment: if i added to the connection it says it's an unused argument (encoding = "latin-1")

Comment: are you using the `DBI` package for connection? encoding is a valid argument for `DBI::dbConnect(...)` and helped me to solve this kind of pb.